# How to make a declared function automatically infer types based on usage?

Tags: typescript

I feel like this should totally be possible in typescript, but it seems as if typescript doesn't properly type this. Is there any way to do this? Here's a super simple example, but I'm specifically looking to automatically infer argument types when passing a function to a react component's prop that takes a callback with a defined type

### Actual

```js
function constrainingFunction(b: number) {
    return b + 1
}

function test(a) { // ERROR: `a` implicitly has an `any` type
    constrainingFunction(a)
}

test(1)
```

### Expected

```
function constrainingFunction(b: number) {
    return b + 1
}

function test(a) { // `a` should properly be inferred as `number`
    constrainingFunction(a)
}

test(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#34738](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34738) for a canonical answer.

TypeScript does not perform [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of function parameters from usage this way, apparently for performance reasons.  According to [this comment by the dev lead for the TS team](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34738#issuecomment-546489078),

> This has been an intentional design constraint since inception; *not* doing this is a key reason TS performance is remotely acceptable.

There's also [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38992#issuecomment-641416618) in a related issue:

> People have asked us hundreds of times why we don't do this; the answer is that it's architecturally impractical to do this in a way that results in stable, performant checking results in anything other than toy programs.

So the `a` parameter will need to be explicitly [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) as `number` in order for this code to work as intended without error.

---

But you don't necessarily need to be the one annotating it yourself.  As both comments above go on to say:

> The "infer from usage" refactor will produce a type for you on an as-requested basis.

> The "infer from usage" refactor is available for this purpose.

So TypeScript *can* infer the type from usage, but not automatically during compilation.  You can specifically request it in an IDE that supports Code Actions like [Visual Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_code-actions-quick-fixes-and-refactorings) or [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/quick-fixes).

If you select the offending `a` parameter, you should see a light bulb, which when clicked, suggests "infer parameter types from usage":

```
function constrainingFunction(b: number) {
  return b + 1
}
//  [ infer parameter types from usage ]
function test(a) { // ERROR: `a` implicitly has an `any` type
  // -------> ~
  constrainingFunction(a)
}

test(1)
```

And if you accept that suggestion, the desired explicit annotation will occur:

```
function constrainingFunction(b: number) { // <-- magic!
  return b + 1
}
function test(a: number) {
  constrainingFunction(a)
}

test(1)
```

Supplementary animated screenshot:

[image: animated screenshot]

So that might be some consolation for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgEIQBmA9gE7IHHE0Cuw8ALgJZ3Ak8AVG4MQvYJIDmAMU49+wABQAjAFwl2YVRAYBKPEVbEm3dg0GqkAaiQBGY8QC+TpAHp3SQLwbgQp2kANpIkjR6SHDikNxh3ACeMNBINAx0YEjsUCDSyAC6bhxcfAJI0aLKIIa4Hl4AogBKdQDydZoABiCtwWAwGLzwvNwYsUgAFiBQSCCC7cCxnXEJbsSeSAC06xurAHxIAH5LQiJiElLAcgpFKhVurm6l3Mr2+oQuLyTg0HCISACCNNEMIwmAqKYrCYCicSSGTyQpKNSaYDaXQGIEmJBmCxWWwOG75C5KErQB4gRHIvSVA7gyEnGEEgTlZ4mW4me6PZ7GW7OIA)

Comment: Damn, this is unfortunate. Thanks for all of the great information though! And I use vim, so no intellisense code actions or whatever they're called for me hah

Comment: There are things like https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim which claim to add IntelliSense and stuff to vim, but I'm not even close to an expert on vim so I won't pretend to know if that's a good idea or not. 

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the link! Yeah I know of a few plugins and such that can enable it, for some reason it feels against my personal philosophy to use them. I will just have to suffer through the discomfort of my own making hah

Comment: And I think to elaborate on my question, I now realize that the specific use case I'm trying to solve for is really "how do you automatically assign arg types when you define a function before its assignment to something like `window.onmousedown`, even though if you defined it inline it would properly infer the function arguments types via contextual typing"